# C#: Multithreaded (task) PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, powershell-cmdlet

Per the subject, I'm trying to put together a multithreaded PowerShell cmdlet and am struggling. I can get the code to run successfully as a console app, and I can get the single threaded cmdlet to work, but haven't been able to merge the two as of yet.

Also, please understand that I am new to C# and have very little clue about what I'm doing, so apologies in advance for the atrocity that is my code. Tried to simplify as much as I could before posting.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sample
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get,"LDAPObject")]
    [OutputType(typeof(List<SearchResult>))]
    public class GetLDAPObjectCmdlet: Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public string searchRoot { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public TimeSpan maxWaitTime { get; set; }

        private List<Task<searchResults>> taskList = new List<Task<searchResults>>();

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            base.BeginProcessing();
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            base.ProcessRecord();

            var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;

            Task<searchResults> searchTask = Task<searchResults>.Factory.StartNew(() => Search(ct, searchRoot));
            taskList.Add(searchTask);

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            bool tasksCompleted = new bool();
            try
            {
                tasksCompleted = Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray(), maxWaitTime);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                WriteWarning("Task cancelled.");
            }

            int resultCount = 0;
            foreach (Task<searchResults> taskItem in taskList)
            {
                if ((taskItem.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) && (taskItem.Result.src != null))
                {
                    resultCount += taskItem.Result.src.Count;
                }

                foreach (string message in taskItem.Result.warningMessages)
                {
                    WriteWarning(message);
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();

            if (tasksCompleted)
            {
                WriteVerbose("The search returned `'" + resultCount.ToString() + "' results in '" + (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString() + "' seconds.");
            }
            else
            {
                WriteVerbose("The search did not complete before the deadline.");
            }
        }

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            base.EndProcessing();

            for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Count; i++)
            {
                taskList[i].Dispose();
            }
        }

        protected override void StopProcessing()
        {
            base.StopProcessing(); 
        }
        
        private static searchResults Search(CancellationToken ct, string searchRootDn)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            searchResults results = new searchResults();
            results.warningMessages = new List<string>();
            results.verboseMessages = new List<string>();

            results.warningMessages.Add("Search root: '" + searchRootDn + "'.");
            DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + searchRootDn);
            try
            {
                Guid guid = searchRoot.Guid;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid search root");
            }

            string searchFilter = "some LDAP filter here";
            results.warningMessages.Add("Search filter: '" + searchFilter + "'.");

            DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
            directorySearcher.SearchRoot = searchRoot;
            directorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            directorySearcher.PageSize = 1000;
            directorySearcher.Filter = searchFilter;

            results.src = directorySearcher.FindAll();
            directorySearcher.Dispose();
            return results;
        }

    }

    class searchResults
    {
        public SearchResultCollection src { get; set; }
        public List<string> warningMessages { get; set; }
        public List<string> verboseMessages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This gives me:

> System.InvalidCastException
> HResult=0x80004002
> Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IDirectorySearch'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{109BA8EC-92F0-11D0-A790-00C04FD8D5A8}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
> Source=System.DirectoryServices
> StackTrace:
> at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_SearchObject()
> at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_InnerList()
> at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_Count()
> at MultiThreadedSearch.GetLDAPObjectCmdlet.ProcessRecord() in C:\Users\obfuscated\GETLDAPObjectCmdlet.cs:line 73
> at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

on the *resultCount += taskItem.Result.src.Count;* line.

Note that I didn't actually need the *searchResult* class; I just introduced it for want of a means by which to allow the Search function to be able to contribute content to *WriteWarning*, *WriteVerbose*, etc.

Thoughts are most appreciated!

Comment: Please note that tasks are not threads - they may use threads, but they are not threads. It's like saying "I'm using multiple tyres (i.e. a vehicle)." Vehicles ***may*** have tyres, but not all do, and tyres aren't vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved my own problem. Unexpectedly, the problem appears to stem from how the DirectorySearcher interface is implemented. Specifically, the results from the LDAP search are not cached until the first call to enumerate the SearchResultsCollection - specifically, when I attempted to access the *Count* property. This is nicely described [here](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.434.1/executing_the_query_and_enumerating_results.html):

> We tend to use the foreach statement to enumerate the results. Unlike some other collection classes in the .NET Framework, SearchResultCollection internally implements its own private IEnumerator object that pulls the results from the directory. Any access to the SearchResultCollection properties, such as inspecting the Count property, will cause the entire result set to be retrieved from the directory and then enumerated. This can have a large impact, especially when returning many results, for a couple of reasons. First, using a foreach loop would allow us to break off the search if necessary, without enumerating all the results completely. This is more efficient, as we break off the search early and do not force the server to return all of the results first. Second, we can process each result as it comes from the server using a foreach loop without waiting for the entire search to complete. Using a for loop in conjunction with the Count property prevents both of these scenarios. As such, we generally recommend using the foreach loop when enumerating our results.